# How to how to install poppler from the .tar file downloaded from poppler official site

Tags: windows, poppler

There is no useful information on the site  describing how to install the file .I have tried extracting the .tar file, installing through command prompt . there is no information available on the web.OS used is windows 11. Its for a project to extract data from images, using OCR. Poppler is used for getting page numbers of the pdf file which will be converted to an image file later in the process."https://poppler.freedesktop.org/" is the site from which I downloaded the file.Is this the right site.Any answer is helpful.Thank you

Comment: Please don't write normal sentences (even question titles or summaries) in all upper-case. Writing in all upper-case is considered shouting, and it's rather rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Done some edits thank you for your valuable feedback

Answer (score 2):

Poppler source is constantly updated, and thus common for Linux and Mac users to build or brew on demand. It is not much different when using Programming Suites like Python, Ruby etc.

Windows users expect one exe, but the poppler utils were built as a spin off from non-commercial licensed xpdf and for personal 32 bit users that is often simpler.

I have given examples for how simple that xpdf unpacking can be for one exe in several posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/68697144/10802527 (how to scan a file list, not used here) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73123537/10802527 (how to use to run a single file) and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73437398/10802527 (running one exe on demand)

Poppler prebuilt binaries are available as 64bit only so the first step after making a work directory is download latest version from https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows using most current

https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/download/v22.04.0-0/Release-22.04.0-0.zip and save to the working folder, then you can use right click `Extract All...` OR

`tar -m -xf Release-22.04.0-0.zip` to unpack in that folder so it should look like in the binary folder
[image]

Now the exe files are in a subdirectory and when using those it is best if that folder is included on the path environment.

RESIST any means to add using set or worse setx simply add folder via system gui, note in some cases after saving the setting it may need log off and log on to stick and in very rare cases even a reboot/restart.

[image]